# can we add String array into StringBuffer or StringBuilder in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

Now I am developing a simple project on Java.In that I include String Builder to append and print strings on console.When I am trying to append string array into string Builder,it prints object instead of array of strings on console.any one please tell whether my try is right or wrong.

Comment: post your code with your story

Comment: what is your expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add `Arrays.toString(yourArray)` if you want to add the representation of your `String` array.
- If it's a multiple-dimension array (e.g. a `String[][])`, then add `Arrays.deepToString(yourArray)` to your `StringBuilder`.
- Adding the `array` itself will add the default `String` representation.
- Finally, if you need control over how you represent your `array` to `String`, you'll need to iterate the elements yourself and add them to the `StringBuilder` in a customized format.

**Edit**

As a side-note, to make this work with arrays of custom `Object`s, you'll probably want to override the `Object.toString` method, otherwise your elements will be printed with the default `String` representation of `Object` (i.e. [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)).

Comment: @Nithya you're welcome! Also see my edit on custom `Object`s.

Comment: is it possible to ignore the '[' and ']' during this `Arrays.toString()`? Because, am trying to append the elements from `String[]` to `StringBuilder` that has some elements already and I do not want to include a `[ and ]` in between.

Comment: @AshokMA you can just remove the 1st and last character, that will consistently remove the square brackets in a one-dimensional array. For multi-dimensional arrays, you probably need to keep them, lest you want to flatten it (in which case, replace any occurrence of the square brackets with empty strings).

Comment: @Mena yes I can do that. But, I am afraid that it will make my code ugly :( However, I found `Apache Commons Lang StringUtils#join()` very useful in this case. :)

Comment: @AshokMA arguably a little and safe string manipulation should be better than adding a dependency to your project, but it really depends on the context.

Comment: @Mena then it comes to ones preference. I prefer clean code over anything. :) However, we are using `StringUtils` in our project already. So, its not a big deal in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Array is an Object. Do not directly append the array. Just iterate on array and append each element of array to your String builder.

```
for(String str : arr) {
    builder.append(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/**
     * <p>Joins the elements of the provided array into a single String
     * containing the provided list of elements.</p>
     *
     * <p>No delimiter is added before or after the list.
     * A <code>null</code> separator is the same as an empty String ("").
     * Null objects or empty strings within the array are represented by
     * empty strings.</p>
     *
     * <pre>
     * StringUtils.join(null, *)                = null
     * StringUtils.join([], *)                  = ""
     * StringUtils.join([null], *)              = ""
     * StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "--")  = "a--b--c"
     * StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], null)  = "abc"
     * StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "")    = "abc"
     * StringUtils.join([null, "", "a"], ',')   = ",,a"
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param array  the array of values to join together, may be null
     * @param separator  the separator character to use, null treated as ""
     * @param startIndex the first index to start joining from.  It is
     * an error to pass in an end index past the end of the array
     * @param endIndex the index to stop joining from (exclusive). It is
     * an error to pass in an end index past the end of the array
     * @return the joined String, <code>null</code> if null array input
     */`

`Apache Commons Lang StringUtils#join().` is so cool. Hope this helps.